# Turning addresses into GPS coordinates into delivery route?

Tags: geolocation

I'm not sure whether this question belongs to StackOverflow, SuperUser, or yet another StackExchange site.

I have a list of locations (prospects I need to meet) I have to drive to, and I'd like to use either Google Maps or Open Street View to build an optimized route.

Are there tools that can do this, eg. they take a CSV list of locations and generate a driving route?

Thank you.

Comment: Google Maps's _Get directions_ lets you enter multiple destinations. Use _Add Destination_. But you'd have to enter the addresses one at a time.

Comment: It's OK, I guess I can automate input through eg. AutoIT. But does Google Maps build an optimized route?

Comment: If you have a hard time finding answers to this question here, try http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks Matt for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is short enough, you could build a custom link with all the locations which might be easier than the AutoIT approach.  Look at the link that allows you to share a map with several route stops, and then use that syntax to chain your locations together.  I think that would be easier than pasting them into the UI which recently changed.